# MS Teams apps added though the graph are sometimes deleted

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I have an issue concerning MS Teams when using the Graph API. This problem might be difficult to reproduce since it does not happen all the time. Basically, we have a test set up that uses a source team that has a couple of apps and creates a copy of that team. To do that with must add the same apps as the source team so we use:

[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/{id}/installedApps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/teamsappinstallation-list?view=graph-rest-1.0)

Right after the POST, which return a 201 Created which is successful if we look at the doc, we use the GET on the same endpoint to make sure the app was added, and it is there.

At the end of the test we get all the apps to make sure everything got copied over. Sometimes, we are missing one app and it is never the same one. I've tried with the beta and v1.0 endpoints and the same issue arise. This test works most of the time, but let's say on 5 runs, it will fail once. This makes this part of the copy very unreliable.

Comment: We have raised a bug, Tracking it internally. We don't have ETA to share when it will be fixed.

Comment: Are you still facing the issue? Also could you please check do you have any app policies set up. Based on the policy, different users might see different apps for the same team. Also, if the policy is changed midway, then the same user might see different set of apps in the same team - before and after the policy change.