# Posted messages and replies are sometimes missing even if we have a successful response

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

This issue is similar to [MS Teams apps added though the graph are sometimes deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62596532/ms-teams-apps-added-though-the-graph-are-sometimes-deleted) in a way since the response tells us that the message / reply was posted successfully, but when visiting the team afterwards, we are missing some. It is also intermittent. So the underlying issue might be related.

We post messages and replies using the Graph API with :

```
POST /teams/{id}/channels/{id}/messages
POST /teams/{id}/channels/{id}/messages/{id}/replies
```

We have tests that creates messages on a brand new team every night and validate that those messages are created successfully. Rarely, the assertion part that checks that all messages and replies were copied over will fail. It is rare but it is still a problem since there is no way to know if it did not work without scanning the whole team afterwards. Also, it is not a problem with the assertion since I went and checked the team in the browser and it was indeed missing replies for a message. I also had a fiddler running and I can see that the post for the replies were successful (we even have the created JSON messages in the response).

Is it possible that we are going too fast for the API and the Graph tell us it's good but it never makes it to the actual teams API behind? As of right now, we have similar issues with channels, apps and messages / replies so I feel like there is an underlying issue that is common to adding items to a team.

Comment: Could you please share graph api request id and time stamp of the issue?

Comment: @Jean-François Deschênes- Could you please share the request/response for failed case?

Comment: Are you still facing this issue? Could you please share the request/response for failed case?

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT Sorry, I was not able to reproduce again. I will update if we still get it.

Comment: Thanks @Jean-FrançoisDeschênes for updates.